# How to process length prefix files in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, fixed-length-record

I have a huge LPF (Length prefixed file) to be processed by Hadoop.

LPF file is of format: (size of 1st  record in 4bytes)(size of 1st column in 2bytes)(1st column)(size of 2nd column)(2nd column)………….(size of nth column)(nth column)
(size of 2nd record)(size of 1st col)(1st col) …………so on...

But then there seems to be no appropriate InputFormat readily available to read the individual records as there is no delimiter to separate individual records or columns.

The input split has to happen at the end of one of the records so that no half record exists in some other block. Otherwise the Record Reader has to know the end of half record so that it can join it with the other half. Please suggest some way to read and process LPF files

Comment: Can you share some example entries from your input file, so we can better understand?

Comment: But it sounds like you'll need to write your own InputFormat and RecordReader

Comment: LPF file is of format: (size of 1st record in 4bytes)(size of 1st column in 2bytes)(1st column)(size of 2nd column)(2nd column)………….(size of nth column)(nth column) (size of 2nd record)(size of 1st col)(1st col) …………so on...

Answer (score 1):

Why exactly are you prevented from splitting this file? There are plenty of file formats with variable-length entries that are split just fine in Hadoop.

Take a look at the `InputFormat` and `RecordReader` classes and see if it would be possible to implement custom versions. If so, this is what you should do.

Answer (score 1):

> LPF file is of format: (size of 1st record in 4bytes)(size of 1st column in 2bytes)(1st column)(size of 2nd column)(2nd column)………….(size of nth column)(nth column) (size of 2nd record)(size of 1st col)(1st col) …………so on..

I can't find much information on google about the LPF format, but with what you describe - no recoverable delimiter between the reords (txt files use the newline character, sequence files have a signature 16 byte header between blocks), you'll need to process the file in a single mapper ('non-splittable').

Now there might be an algorithm that allows you to seek to a random position in the input file (assuming it's not compressed with a non-splittable compression format, such as gzip).

For example, you could seek to a random position in the file, read the next 4096 bytes into a buffer and attempt to examine the recover the record from that position. When you interpret a record or column size that is improbable (-ve or too large, without knowing more about the file format i can't speculate further), shift the buffer left 1 byte and start trying to recover the record again.

Obviously this isn't an efficient algorithm, but you might be able to build on it with some more knowledge / experience of the format

Eitherway, you'll definitely need to write your own InputFormat and RecordReader.

Comment: I have found a Composite Input Split class in the following link http://people.apache.org/~tomwhite/MAPREDUCE-1623/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/join/CompositeInputSplit.html Any example demonstrating how exactly to use it would be very helpful...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a lot of those files, I would recommend to set the files to non splitable (just extend your FileInputFormat and set the isSplitable() functions return to false)

Another way is to set the blocksize for every file you want to process seperat when creating it. this is possible if you already knew the size of the file you want to write

Comment: I have a single large LPF file. Since the size of each record varies I cannot decide the blocksize which will fit in whole number of records.

Comment: is it possible to split this file? to preprocess several smaller files where the right sizes are taken into account?

Comment: I have found a Composite Input Split class in the following link http://people.apache.org/~tomwhite/MAPREDUCE-1623/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/join/CompositeInputSplit.html Any example demonstrating how exactly to use it would be very helpful...